# special characters replaced by question mark

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, stylesheet

My website is replacing an apostrophe (') with a question mark (?) while rendering the page.

See the deal - my kitchen cook's at

```
 www.dealschintu.com
```

It is a simple HTML page written by me which does the following

1. Connect to MySQL database
2. Retrieve title
3. Display

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: what code do you need?

Comment: The php which connects and gets the title

Comment: here you go - <a href="<?php echo $row[?] ?>" title="<?php echo $row[?] ?> <?php echo $row[?] ?>" id="A_5"><img src="http://xyz/<?php echo $row[?] ?>" alt="xyz <?php echo $row[?] ?> deals" id="IMG_6" /></a>

Comment: I have masked some of the stuff in my previous comment

Comment: Please add it to the original post using the `edit` link under the question. If you want to mask stuff use stuff like `a href="link">` instead, keep the integrity of the comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the php file encoding from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

Add this between the `<head>` tags of your website:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

It should do the trick.